# Basic auth with jQuery: Access to restricted URI denied code: "1012" (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, basic-authentication

I am trying to log into my Netgear router using JavaScript (jQuery):

```
username = "admin";
password = "myrouterpassword";
url = "http://192.168.1.1";
async = false;
type = "GET";
timeout = 3000;
$.ajax({url:url, type:type, async:async,
        username:username, password:password, 
        success: function(reponse) {.. stuff ..}, 
        error: function(error) {.. stuff ..}
      });
```

This returns an "Access to restricted URI denied" error with Firefox and a "NetworkError: A network error occurred" with Chrome. I do not believe this is a cross-domain problem as I have a call I am making with an extremely similar jQuery construct to another resource at 192.168.1.2 and it's working like a charm (except that is not password protected, so I am not using the username and password fields).

My jQuery version is 1.9.1. I have tried several variants here. For example adding this to the ajax options:

```
xhrFields:{ withCredentials: true }
```

And I also tried not using the username and password fields and using headers instead computing the auth with Base 64 and using this:

```
headers:{'Authorization':auth}
```

I also tried the older recommended approach:

```
beforeSend:function(req) { req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth); }
```

When I access this router using Python on a backend, it totally works:

```
passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, baseurl, username, password)
authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
devhandle= urllib2.urlopen(baseurl+'/DEV_device.htm')
devcontent=devhandle.read()
```

This gives me the list of devices attached to this router. I really need to do this in Javascript and knowing that I am able to connect to other devices in the exact same domain (192.168.1.x) suggests it ought to be doable. Open to all suggestions and any help is really appreciated!

**ADDITIONAL INFO**: I added *dataType:"html"* and the error changed to *NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI*. Adding *dataType:"json"* instead causes the same thing. When I changed it to *dataType:"jsonp"* and had *xhrFields:{ withCredentials: true }* present as well, I saw the router's login box pop-up all of a sudden! So, it is clearly reaching the router. I don't want this obviously - the login should happen silently, but it is something nonetheless. I get this back now in the error message when I log in: *{"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}*. The login popup is transient (naturally because once I have logged-in, it doesn't prompt me again). Still tinkering with it. If I get it to work, I will update. If there are some ideas, please let me know.

**CHROME CONSOLE INFO**: This is what I see in the console:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://192.168.1.1/?callback=jQuery19109538986752741039_1379841839394&_=1379841839396". jquery-1.9.1.js:8336
send jquery-1.9.1.js:8336
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-1.9.1.js:7978
ajaxnow mainscreen.htm:79
onclick mainscreen.htm:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

ajaxnow() is a function in my script that makes the .ajax call.

Comment: For the domain to be considered the same, the host (all of the ip address), protocol (http vs https) and port must all match exactly, is this the case?

Comment: I went and double checked. Yes, exactly the same. No SSL, no port differences (ie the accessible device is at 192.168.1.2:80 and the router at 192.168.1.1:80). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running into cross domain issues, and you want to disable the check you can run chrome without web security:

```
chromium-browser --disable-web-security
```

Goes without saying that this is extremely dangerous if your browser has cookies/saved passwords for **any** sensitive sites.

Comment: The password and username are provided by a backend (ie wont actually be set up like I showed above though I did try this to completely eliminate the possibility of any backend problems). I will try your suggestion to check for cross domain problems Christophe. Funny thing is that this is working (minus the auth) for another device at 192.168.1.2 which makes me think this should not be a crossdomain problem, though I could be wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add "http://" to your url.

Then, python doesn't enforce same-origin policy but browsers do. Browsers will allow/deny cross-origin requests according to the Access-Control-Allow-* headers of OPTIONS response from the target host. [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). So unless you can modify the routers' page/response or running a security-ripped version of browser, it's not gonna happen in the browser on a different host.

At last, maybe node.js is what you should go with.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions ledzep2. I left out the http:// by accident. They are actually there in the code (and edited to show it here now). Also, given that the javascript is successfully able to access another device with the same domain and port number, it doesn't seem like a cross domain issue (of course, I could be wrong). I will look at node.js in the future also. Still stuck on this though.

Comment: Maybe you can provide more information from Chrome Console or   tcpdump.

Comment: Added it above. It seems like the jsonp typed call gets through but then there are issues with the type because what the router is returning is html. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: This is expected because tags like <script>, <img>, <iframe> doesn't enforce cross-origin check. And jsonp works exactly this way by putting a script tag to the body. And that's why it doesnt work in your case.

Answer (score -1):

I may have inadvertently stubbled across a fix for this 192.168.1.1:80 error message when you try to reset a net gear router. The short answer that worker for me (after trying all the suggestions posted) was to reconnect and reboot everything.

Eventually, after being unable to secure the network for 2 days but with internet connection, my outlook froze whenever my mac laptop was connected to it and the internet they went down altogether. I am staying in a rented apartment on vacation so had no install CD for the Netgear WNR1000v3 router. 
After losing connection altogether I re-rebotted the router and re connected all connections (no good), and finally rebooted the cable modem ((Scientific Atlanta) and got the internet back and whilst the same 192.168.1.1:80 message came on typing 192.168.1.1 into a browser, it finally let me enter the default username and  password (user, password), to log into the router (via 192.168.1.1) and allowed access to all the settings to include changing the password settings.